# C++ variable declation syntax

Tags: c++, c, syntax, declaration

I recently came across this construct:
    int(m);
which seems to be equivalent to:
    int m;

Oddly, I have never seen this particular idiom before.  Can someone point me to a reference where I can read the spec on this, or just explain directly?  Does this also work in straight C?

Thanks,
ConfusedDeveloper

Comment: While this is perfectly legal syntax for declaring an integer, for the sake of your fellow developers change it to `int m;`.

Answer (score 11):

It is not an "idiom". It is just a redundant pair of parentheses. Grammatically, they can be there, but they serve no purpose.

Sometimes similar seemingly superfluous parentheses can be used to resolve ambiguity in C++ declarations, like

```
int a(int());
```

which declares a function can be turned into

```
int a((int()));
```

which is equivalent to

```
int a = int();
```

and defines a variable. But this is not exactly what you have in your case.

Comment: Minor nitpick: it's not always redundant. For instance, you can write `cout << int(n)`, but not `cout << int n`.

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful. BTW, definition of idiom: an expression sanctioned by use that is peculiar to a language.  Seems an appropriate description.

Comment: @suszterpatt: The question was specifically about declarations. Your example does not involve any declarations at all. Your example is about `()` in expressions, which is a completely different story.

Answer (score 1):

It's also used to cast.  Like,

```
double m= 10.0;
int n= int(m);
```

Comment: The question is about declarations, and this is not a declaration at all, just something that looks similar.

Comment: @aschepler: Yes. Since it looks similar, that is why I post it. Just wanted to tell him that this is also how it is used. :-)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answers, sometimes declarator has to be parenthesized.
For example:

```
struct A {};

struct B { A a; };

namespace N {
  struct B { int a; };

  void f()
  {
    A (::B::*p) = &::B::a; // this () cannot be omitted
  }
}
```

If `()` is omitted in the above code, compiler recognizes a consecutive nested
name specifier `A::B` instead of `A` and `::B`, and will issue an error.
This parenthesis is necessary, but sometimes leads to a misleading situation.

```
struct A {
  int m;
  A() {}
  A( int ) {} // this isn't called
};

int i;

int main()
{
  A(i); // this is a declaration
  i.m = 1; // ok
}
```

In the above code, `A(i)` is a declaration(and also a definition in this case) of an object `i`,
instead of a constructor call expression with an `int` argument `i`.

Hope this helps.