# Re-declaration error when using a prior variable in anonymous instance creation

Tags: c++, g++

g++ gives a re-declaration error when using previously declared variable in anonymous instance creation.

I have the following code in my "weird.cpp" source file:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int i = 0;
  int j = int ( i );
  int ( i );
}
```

The error i am getting is,

```
weird.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
weird.cpp:7: error: redeclaration of ‘int i’
weird.cpp:5: error: ‘int i’ previously declared here
```

I have tried this in mac and linux with versions 4.2 and 4.7 respectively. I have also tried with other types instead of int. The result is the same error. Can anyone help me understand this problem? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you think "anonymous instance creation" is, but what you are doing here does not open a new variable scope.

Comment: It seems you don't fully understand the behavior of parentheses in C++.

Comment: @ChrisHayes Can you clarify your comment a little bit more? In my example, i am trying to create an instance whose scope is only that particular line.

Comment: First of all, a variable whose scope only lasts for one line is useless. Second, new scopes are created in braces (`{}`). Third, you can't introduce a new scope in the middle of an expression. You'd have to use something like `{ int i; }`.

Comment: @Aesthete It appears so. I wanted to create a anonymous instance of a type. Let's say A is a type that takes an "int" in it's constructor, if i do  { int i = 0; A( i ); }, i get this error.

Comment: ChrisHayes Aesthete Thanks for your inputs. I think the relevant issue is discussed in [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727993/c-variable-declation-syntax]

Comment: So the point is you don't know what parentheses do.. I'm still interested what you mean "anonymous instance of a type".

Comment: @Aesthete Googling anonymous object gave this link here [http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/814-anonymous-variables-and-objects/]

Comment: Ok I understand what you mean, but this example doesn't use anonymous variables. Is the an actual problem you're trying to solve? Do you have any more code that shows what you can't do?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the parentheses you're using here don't do anything.

```
int i = 0;
int j = int(i); // This is casting i to an int. It's already an int.
int j = i; // This does the same as the last line.
int (i); // This is redeclaring an int named i, which had already been done.
int i; // This is the same as the last line.
```

What you are saying about an object accepting an `int` in it's constructor doesn't make sense.

```
struct A { A(int) {} };
int i;
A obj(i); // A instance named obj which takes integer i as constructor argument.
```

I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve here, perhaps this?

```
int i = 0;
int j = i;
{
    int i; // In another scope, shadowing the first i for scope duration.
}
```

Comment: The line which gives the re-declaration error is the line where an anonymous object is constructed. This anonymous object refers to an earlier declared variable.

Comment: There is no anonymous object, only variable declarations and an assignment.

Answer (score 2):

You could be forgiven for being confused by this, it's a case of C++'s context-sensitive nature and how that is interpreted by the compiler.

```
int (i);
```

is being treated as a declaration of "i" (and since you already have a variable called i in this scope and have not enabled -Wno-shadow, it's not allowing this).

Contrast with the following case, which doesn't compile: (see http://ideone.com/QuwnTC)

```
#include <iostream>

class Bark {
public:
    Bark(const char* msg, const char*) {
         std::cout << "Hear ye, hear ye. " << msg << std::endl;
    }
};

void bark(const char* i) {
    Bark (i); // error here.
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv) {
    bark("wtf");
}
```

It complains that Bark (i) shadows "i"s declaration.

However, both of the following DO compile: http://ideone.com/dcGMET

```
void bark(const char* i) {
    Bark (i + 1);
}
```

or having two arguments inside the parenthesis: (http://ideone.com/tMzSY9)

```
#include <iostream>

class Bark {
public:
    Bark(const char* msg, const char*) {
         std::cout << "Hear ye, hear ye. " << msg << std::endl;
    }
};

void bark(const char* i) {
    Bark (i, NULL);
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv) {
    bark("wtf");
}
```

Clearly, the treatment of "type (name)" here is some sort of special case, and you might want to raise this with the compiler developers.